# python google sheets automation

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-workspace

i want to update the multiple sheets within the same spreadsheet using python. I am able to append data to the main spreadsheet using the spreadsheetID but i can't find a way to update the sheets within the main spreadsheet with different gid

```
SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID = '1nt7cmF5nmWcoBy9r8Yxoz670C97FH1mzKuLarararar'
SAMPLE_RANGE_NAME = 'A1:W1'

def gservice():
    # If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.json.
    SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']

    # The ID and range of a sample spreadsheet.
    
    """Shows basic usage of the Sheets API.
    Prints values from a sample spreadsheet.
    """
    creds = None
    # The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.json'):
        creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
            token.write(creds.to_json())

    
    return build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)


sheet=gservice().spreadsheets()

def APPEND_GSHEET(some_data):
    # list1 = [[11,22,33]]
    resource = {
    "majorDimension": "ROWS",
    "values": some_data
    }
    sheet.values().append(spreadsheetId=SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID,
    range="A1:B11",
    body=resource,
    valueInputOption="USER_ENTERED"
    ).execute()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that in order to put the values to the specific sheet in a Google Spreadsheet, there are 2 patterns.

#### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, the values are put into the specific sheet in Google Spreadsheet using the sheet ID. When this is reflected in your script, please modify it as follows. In this case, please modify `APPEND_GSHEET` as follows.

```py
def APPEND_GSHEET(some_data):
    sheetId = 123456789 # Please set your sheet ID.

    res = sheet.get(spreadsheetId=SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID).execute()
    sheetObj = [s for s in res["sheets"] if s["properties"]["sheetId"] == sheetId]
    if sheetObj != []:
        sheetName = sheetObj[0]["properties"]["title"]
        r = "'" + sheetName + "'!A1:B11"
        resource = {
            "majorDimension": "ROWS",
            "values": some_data
        }
        sheet.values().append(spreadsheetId=SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID, range=r, body=resource, valueInputOption="USER_ENTERED").execute()
```

- In this modification, the sheet ID is converted to the sheet name. And, the value is put into the specific sheet in Google Spreadsheet using the sheet name.

#### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, the values are put into the specific sheet in Google Spreadsheet using the sheet name. When this is reflected in your script, please modify it as follows. In this case, please modify `APPEND_GSHEET` as follows.

```py
def APPEND_GSHEET(some_data):
    sheetName = "Sheet2" # Please set your sheet name.

    r = "'" + sheetName + "'!A1:B11"
    resource = {
        "majorDimension": "ROWS",
        "values": some_data
    }
    sheet.values().append(spreadsheetId=SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID, range=r, body=resource, valueInputOption="USER_ENTERED").execute()
```

#### Reference:

- [Method: spreadsheets.values.append](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/append)